# How to change a value in a mock object using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I want to test `validate` method and I have the following classes:

**Example class**

```
public class Example {
  private int status;
  
  public boolean validate(ComplexObject complexObject) {
    if (status == 1) {
        //  do something...
    }
    
    if (status == -1) {
        complexObject.setErrorMessage("Some error occured!");
    }
    
    return status != -1;
  }
}
```

**ComplexObject class**

```
public class ComplexObject {

    //  This is a complicated object which I
    //  do not want to reproduce
    String errorMessage;

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
}
```

**ExampleTest class**

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ExampleTest {

    @Mock
    ComplexObject complexObject;

    @Test
    public void testValidationWithErrorMessage() {
        Example example = new Example();

        assertThat(example.validate(complexObject)).isFalse();

        //  The problem: complexObject.getErrorMessage() result is null
        assertThat(complexObject.getErrorMessage()).isEqualTo("Some error message");
    }
}
```

I want to perform a test that mocking this ComplexObject but if I have an error message, I want to get it.
In the actual code it works, but with the mock object when it perform:

```
complexObject.setErrorMessage("Some error occured!");
```

I end up getting `null`.

Can I mock `ComplexObject` and still get the message error when I test it?

Comment: You can't expect ClassA to call `mock.setProperty("whatever")` and later on `assertTrue(mock.getProperty().equals("whatever"))` - the getter will return null as well. You should verify that the setter was called with expected arguments instead.

Comment: It doesnt really show whether you want (or why you want) your mock to behave like the real ComplexObject, but it does show that you want to check whether `ComplexObject.setErrorMessage(...)` was called with an expected parameter. And in that case, you don't want to assert on the getter, you want to verify how the setter was called. Using spies just to get your getters/setters to work properly is kind of an overkill, and shows that the test should perhaps be revised.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way, since you're in direct control of ComplexObject, would be to do this:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ExampleTest {

    @Mock
    ComplexObject complexObject;

    @Test
    public void testValidationWithErrorMessage() {
        //setup mock
        when(complexObject.getErrorMessage()).thenReturn("Some error message");
        Example example = new Example();

        assertThat(example.validate(complexObject)).isFalse();

        //  The problem: complexObject.getErrorMessage() result is null
        assertThat(complexObject.getErrorMessage()).isEqualTo("Some error message");
    }
}
```

But note that this makes the test completely pointless. If you want to test whether `Example` sets an error message on the `ComplexObject`, exactly once, you will want to `verify(complexObject.setErrorMessage(anyString(), times(1))`

if you however want to verify the number of times the error message has been set, and the actual `String errorMessage` - then you'll need to use the ValueCaptor / ArgumentCaptor.

And when you start using those, generally you want to re-think your tests.

Because `verify(complexObject.setErrorMessage("Wrong error message"))` will actually throw an exception that `"Wrong error message" was expected, but was called with "Some error message" instead`

so rethink whether you really want to use captors. they make the tests generally a bit dirty.

Edit:

Generally, mocks do nothing when their methods are called, and if the methods are supposed to return anything - they return null. So if you want to observe an actual class (have it behave like it should, but still being able to verify number of calls on it, and their actual params) you should consider using Spies insted. Sounds like you wanna verify that your spy has been called with ".setErrorMessage("Some error message")` exactly once, verifying both the argument, and the number of method calls.

You should give mocks to methods you want to test, you should use spies to observe what happens while you're testing something. As mentioned above, try not to make dirty test, and the documentation will tell you that using spies is generally not a great thing and that you should re-think your test, but there are valid usecases for them too. Spy is generally just a mock, that actually executes the Class's real methods, and behaves like the class would.

So if you know your expected error string in advance, simplest thing to do is this:

```
verify(complexObject.setErrorMessage("Some error message"), times(1))
```

As you will be unable to make the connection between the "setter" and the "getter" without a spy.

Here's a restructured test for you:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ExampleTest {

    @Mock
    ComplexObject complexObject;

    @Test
    public void testValidationWithErrorMessage() {
        String expectedMessage = "Some error message";
        //setup mock
//        when(complexObject.getErrorMessage()).thenReturn(expectedMessage);
        Example example = new Example();

        assertThat(example.validate(complexObject)).isFalse();

        //  The problem: complexObject.getErrorMessage() result is null
        verify(complexObject.setErrorMessage(expectedMessage), times(1))
        // the next line is pointless
//assertThat(complexObject.getErrorMessage()).isEqualTo(expectedMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice how I didn't convert it to a spy, on purpose, because from your post - you don't need one. A mock will do just fine.

Comment: For bonus points, if `Example` class sets many different errorMessages on the complexObject, abstract that away into a ErrorMessageSetter class, and then do tests on that, instead of the ComplexObject :)  But using spies for all three, would essentially be something like an integration test for them *shrug* but still doable with mocks, nicely and cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging in Mockito documentation I found the following:

> Once created, a mock will remember all interactions. Then you can selectively verify whatever interactions you are interested in.
>
> By default, for all methods that return a value, a mock will return either null, a primitive/primitive wrapper value, or an empty collection, as appropriate. For example 0 for an int/Integer and false for a boolean/Boolean.

[Mockito verify documentation](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.11.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#1)

What it means is that Mockito remember all the interactions and allow you via `verify` method to check if the code performed some method and check its arguments.

If you want to mock a simple object, this will do.
But if you want to check something inside the object this will get complicated.
This is why we have `capture`.

> Mockito verifies argument values in natural java style: by using an equals() method. This is also the recommended way of matching arguments because it makes tests clean & simple. In some situations though, it is helpful to assert on certain arguments after the actual verification.

[Mockito Captor documentation](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html)

So in this case, this is what you need to have in the `ExampleTest` class:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ExampleTest {

    @Mock
    ComplexObject complexObject;

    @Captor private ArgumentCaptor<String> complexObjectArgumentCaptor;

    @Test
    public void testValidationWithErrorMessage() {
        Example example = new Example();

        assertThat(example.validate(complexObject)).isFalse();

        verify(complexObject).setErrorMessage(complexObjectArgumentCaptor.capture());
        var validationResult = complexObjectArgumentCaptor.getValue();
        assertThat(validationResult).isEqualTo("Some error occured!");
    }
}
```

Comment: spot on. he'll pluck what he needs from our answers :)